# regex for comment

Tags: antlr4

I created a language with antlr but I have problem with comment regex. in my language comments for a line just begin with "$$" and for multi line begin with '$$' and end with '$$'. i used 
below regex

```
COMMENT : '$$'.*?'$$' -> skip;
LINE_COMMENT : '$$'.*?'\n' -> skip;
```

but can't work properly some times.

Comment: Suppose the input contains two line comments (on separate lines). The first rule matches the span of characters from the first '$$' on the first line to the second '$$' on the next line, so the lexer returns a block comment by mistake. I suggest you do what other languages do, and that is to provide other delimiters for a block comment. Or, if you really want to keep with '$$', you will need to add a predicate to the block comment to indicate when the input should be considered instead as a line comment.

Comment: Note that the patterns are **not** regular expressions, even though they share some lexems with the RegEx language!